# Group by two columns count

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection and i am trying to get the count of the rows , as per the below implementation i am getting result as below , but i am expecting the count as 4 .

```
List<Row> CoAs = new List<Row>()
{
    new Row() { year=1987, name="doll" },
    new Row() { year=1988, name="doll" },
    new Row() { year=2000, name="toy" },
    new Row() { year=2000, name="ball" }
};

int gc = CoAs.GroupBy(c => c.name.ToLower().Trim(),
                           c => c.year.ToString()).Count();
Console.WriteLine(gc);
```

Result = 3 ;
But i am expecting Result = 4 ;

where i want to exclude records which are getting duplicated in both columns like this

```
new Row() { year=1987, name="doll" },
new Row() { year=1987, name="doll" }
```

Answer (score 5):

With the code:

```
CoAs.GroupBy(c => c.name.ToLower().Trim(),c => c.year.ToString())
```

you're saying to group by the name property, and that each group has to be a list of the years having that name (you're using this [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload).

To group by both the properties you should do this :

```
int gc = 
CoAs
.GroupBy(c => new { Name=c.name.ToLower().Trim(), Year=c.year })
.Count();
```

where, in the `keySelector` argument you specify both the properties as keys of your groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the duplicate item on these two properties then:

```
int gc = CoAs
          .GroupBy(x => new {x.name.ToLower().Trim(), x.year} )
          .Count();
```

or you can write your own distinct method according to properties:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
int gCount = CoAs.DistinctBy(p => new { p.name.ToLower().Trim(), p.year}).Count();
```

Comment: First this won't compile. Second it will still give output 3. digEmAll answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are counting the groups, not the rows. If you want to count the rows after you have grouped then do this:

```
int gc =
    CoAs
        .GroupBy(c => c.name.ToLower().Trim(), c => c.year.ToString())
        .Sum(xs => xs.Count());
```

Alternatively you could just do this:

```
int gc = CoAs.Count();
```